# How to increase all ulimit at once?

Tags: linux, ulimit

I don't know how to remove all limits from my computer at right way, so I did a *little* command:

```
sudo su
ulimit -a 9999999
ulimit -b 9999999
ulimit -c 9999999
ulimit -d 9999999
ulimit -e 9999999
ulimit -f 9999999
ulimit -g 9999999
ulimit -h 9999999
ulimit -i 9999999
ulimit -k 9999999
ulimit -k 9999999
ulimit -l 9999999
ulimit -m 9999999
ulimit -n 9999999
ulimit -o 9999999
ulimit -p 9999999
ulimit -q 9999999
ulimit -r 9999999
ulimit -s 9999999
ulimit -t 9999999
ulimit -u 9999999
ulimit -v 9999999
ulimit -v 9999999
ulimit -w 9999999
ulimit -x 9999999
ulimit -y 9999999
ulimit -z 9999999
```

Is there a right and shorter way to this?

Comment: This won't work outside of the `su`; you might consider a `for` loop in shell

Comment: Actually I need to change these values for the user `openfire`. I read somewhere that if I do it on `su`, it'll change values from every user, but I might be wrong. About the `for`, it seems a little wrong for me to do it (not more than I'm already doing), so I'm here asking for a more *elegant* way.

Comment: The limits only affect the current shell.  And you don't need so many: there are actually only a dozen on most systems, not all 26 from a to z.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set all ulimits unlimited for all users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068414/how-do-i-set-all-ulimits-unlimited-for-all-users)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28068611/2299450):

```
 for opt in $(ulimit -a | sed 's/.*\-\([a-z]\)[^a-zA-Z].*$/\1/'); do
     ulimit -$opt ulimited
 done
```