# How do I set all ulimits unlimited for all users?

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit

Yes, I want to remove **all** `ulimits` and set them to `unlimited`. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Read notably the [bash builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) documentation & [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
 for opt in $(ulimit -a | sed 's/.*\-\([a-z]\)[^a-zA-Z].*$/\1/'); do
     ulimit -$opt ulimited
 done
```

Caution, check output of `ulimit -a | sed 's/.*\-\([a-z]\)[^a-zA-Z].*$/\1/'` first, `ulimit -a` output may differ from system to system.